# How to remove shift-reduce conflict in yacc grammar?

Tags: yacc, shift-reduce-conflict

I have the following grammar:

```
Expression
    : SimpleExpression {$$ = $1;};
    | SimpleExpression LTnum SimpleExpression
        { MkLeftC($1, $2); $$ = MkRightC($3, $2); }
    | SimpleExpression LEnum SimpleExpression
        { MkLeftC($1, $2); $$ = MkRightC($3, $2); }
    | SimpleExpression EQnum SimpleExpression
        { MkLeftC($1, $2); $$ = MkRightC($3, $2); }
    | SimpleExpression NEnum SimpleExpression
        { MkLeftC($1, $2); $$ = MkRightC($3, $2); }
    | SimpleExpression GEnum SimpleExpression
        { MkLeftC($1, $2); $$ = MkRightC($3, $2); }
    | SimpleExpression GTnum SimpleExpression
        { MkLeftC($1, $2); $$ = MkRightC($3, $2); }
    ;

SimpleExpression
    : PLUSnum Term op_terms
        { $$ = MakeTree(AddOp,$3,$2); }
    | MINUSnum Term op_terms
        { $$ = MakeTree(SubOp,$3,$2); }
    ;

op_terms
    : PLUSnum Term
        { $$ = MakeTree(AddOp,NullExp(),$2); }
    | PLUSnum Term op_terms
        { $$ = MakeTree(AddOp,$3,$2); }
    | MINUSnum Term
        { $$ = MakeTree(SubOp,NullExp(),$2); }
    | MINUSnum Term op_terms
        { $$ = MakeTree(SubOp,$3,$2); }
    | ORnum Term
        { $$ = MakeTree(OrOp,NullExp(),$2); }
    | ORnum Term op_terms
        { $$ = MakeTree(OrOp,$3,$2); }
    ;
```

I get the following shift-reduce conflicts in the y.output file:

```
51: shift/reduce conflict (shift 74, reduce 57) on GTnum
51: shift/reduce conflict (shift 75, reduce 57) on NEnum
51: shift/reduce conflict (shift 76, reduce 57) on EQnum
51: shift/reduce conflict (shift 77, reduce 57) on GEnum
51: shift/reduce conflict (shift 78, reduce 57) on LEnum
51: shift/reduce conflict (shift 79, reduce 57) on LTnum
state 51
    Expression : SimpleExpression .  (57)
    Expression : SimpleExpression . LTnum SimpleExpression  (58)
    Expression : SimpleExpression . LEnum SimpleExpression  (59)
    Expression : SimpleExpression . EQnum SimpleExpression  (60)
    Expression : SimpleExpression . NEnum SimpleExpression  (61)
    Expression : SimpleExpression . GEnum SimpleExpression  (62)
    Expression : SimpleExpression . GTnum SimpleExpression  (63)
```

I need help with removing these conflicts. What am I doing wrong here? I have tried to set precedence rules but they somehow don't seem to work here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange grammar. It should be of this form:

```
Expression
    : SimpleExpression {$$ = $1;};
    | Expression LTnum SimpleExpression
    | Expression LEnum SimpleExpression
    | Expression EQnum SimpleExpression
    | Expression NEnum SimpleExpression
    | Expression GEnum SimpleExpression
    | Expression GTnum SimpleExpression
    ;
```

i.e. using left-recursion.

Strange tree too. It should be of the general form:

```
$$ = MkBinaryNode($1,$2,$3);
```

Comment: I changed the grammar to the one above but I still get the same conflicts.